# Changing window properties in Visual C# from code-behind (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, window, code-behind

I want the background of my WPF window to change in a specific situation (but could as well be any other property). Let's suppose the name of the window is `myWindow1`. If I treat the window just like any other item (like you would do in Windows Forms), myWindow1 doesn't seem to have a Background property to set; only read-only properties are shown in auto-complete. If I try creating a new object like this:
`myWindow1 w1 = new myWindow1();`
then w1 seems to have all the right properties available for changing in autocomplete, including background, and the IDE shows no errors. But when I try starting the program, it hangs.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the best practice for changing WPF windows properties from code-behind in Visual C# 2013?

Comment: Are you sure myWindow1 is an instance of Window. It should have a background property. Also you cannot write new myWindow1()

Comment: how can you use the MyWindow1 methods with out creating an instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this from XAML.

```
< Window x:Class="WPF1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}">

</Grid>
```

this is also dynamic resource

```
<Window x:Class="WPF1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
     Background="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
 <Window.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="LightGray"/>
 </Window.Resources>
<Grid >
  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

It also be done with static resource

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't create a new instance of the same windows. Because it overrides the one you're trying to launch.
   2.To reach your goal, I would probably use a fancy animation something like:

   ```
   function changeBGColor(this migth be an event handler)
   {
            Storyboard sb=new storyboard();
            ColorAnimation ca=new ColorAnimation();
            ca.From = Colors.Teal;
            ca.By = Colors.Green;
            ca.To = Colors.YellowGreen;
            ca.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("(Background.BackgroundBrus).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
            myWindow1.beginStoryboard(sb);
   }
   ```

Comment: I used ColorAnimation but on a grid, like user2526236 suggested, and achieved what I wanted to. Changing the background property of the grid was enough, but I needed to time it and then go back to the first status, so animations were useful in controlling the flow of events (animation.complete(function)). Still, I wonder if it's possible to edit the window's properties while the window is loaded, and how.

Comment: Yes you can. Remember that there's an instance of the mainWindow as soon as you create it! you can do something like this:    `this.width=230;`